# Batch renaming TV Series

Tags: bash, rename, for

My iTunes library is on a NAS (WD MyCloud 4TB), and I have a number of TV series, organised by iTunes library in the usual:

'TV Shows' folder:

```
TV Show 1

|------------- Series 1
               |-----------01 Episode Name.m4v
               |-----------02 Episode Name.m4v
               |...
|------------- Series 2
               |-----------01 Episode Name.m4v
               |...
|...
TV Show 2
|------------- Series 1
               |-----------01 Episode Name.m4v
               |-----------02 Episode Name.m4v
               |...
|------------- Series 2
               |-----------01 Episode Name.m4v
               |...
|...
```

I have hard linked the whole TV folder to another folder, called Infuse. This folder will be read by the Infuse app on my Apple TV [this allows me to bypass having a computer with iTunes permanently switched on], so I need to rename all the hard-linked files as such:

```
TV Show 1
|------------- Series 1
               |-----------TV Show 1 - S0101 Episode Name.m4v
               |-----------TV Show 1 - S0102 Episode Name.m4v
               |...
|------------- Series 2
               |-----------TV Show 1 - S0201 Episode Name.m4v
               |...
|...
TV Show 2
|------------- Series 1
               |-----------TV Show 2 - S0101 Episode Name.m4v
               |-----------TV Show 2 - S0102 Episode Name.m4v
               |...
|------------- Series 2
               |-----------TV Show 2 - S0201 Episode Name.m4v
               |...
|...
```

I have so far found the solution (for example TV Show 1, Season 1 folder):

`cd` into each season folder for each show and run

`for f in *; do mv $f "TV Show 1 E01S$f"; done`

but this is really time consuming as I then need to

```
cd ../Season 2/
for f in *; do mv $f "TV Show 1 E02S$f"; done
cd ../Sesaon 3/

...

cd ../../TV Show 2/Season 1/
for f in *; do mv $f "TV Show 2 E01S$f"; done
...
```

and what I ideally want is to script pulling the name from the grandparent directory and the season number from the parent directory so I can write one short bash script and run it. Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
a=[TV Show folder]
b=[Season folder]
c=[each episode]

for c in each a/b/
mv $c "$a - S0$bE$c"    (or)   rename $c "$a - S0$bE$c"
done
```

Can you help me implement it with a number of for loops or specific command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having done something very similar recently I already had a script.

```
for f in */*/*
do
  destdir=${f%/*}
  tvshow=${f%%/*}
  season=${destdir#*/}
  episode=${f##*/}
  # Get season number
  seasonnum=${season##* }

  dest=$(printf "%s/%s - S%02iE%s" "$destdir" "$tvshow" $seasonnum "$episode")
  echo "mv -- \"$f\" \"$dest\""
  # mv -- "$f" "$dest"
done
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is amazing and completely works - such a fast response too!!!

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv -n '(*)/(Series (<->))/(<->)(*)' '$1/$2/$1 - S${(l:2::0:)3}E${(l:2::0:)4}$5'
```

(remove `-n` when happy).

- `<->` is `<x-y>` for numbers `x` to `y` but with neither `x` nor `y` provided, so any (decimal) number.
- `${(l:2::0:)var}`: left-pad of width 2 with `0`s

Same with `perl`'s `rename`:

```
rename -n 's{./(.*)/Series (\d+)/\K\d+}{
             sprintf "%s - S%02dE%02d", $1, $2, $&}se' ./*/*/*
```